# How do I look for matching data in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database table for a todo list application, and i need a way to track tasks which are dependant on other tasks, I already have a table with ID,title, description, IsComplete and a DependsOnTask column, containing the unique identifier for the task another given task is dependant on.

the problem is, when I try the below in SQL it doesn't give any results!

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [id]
      ,[title]
      ,[description]
      ,[complete]
      ,[DependsOnTask]
  FROM [master].[dbo].[ToDoItems] where ToDoItems.id =ToDoItems.DependsOnTask;
```

So my question is, is there a way to find all records with a unique identifier matching DependsOnTask?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is a bad practice to use `master` database for user tables. Just a note! :)

Comment: I do know this but it's not production code :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT tdi.*, dot.*
FROM dbo.ToDoItems tdi JOIN
     dbo.ToDoItems dot
     ON dot.id = tdi.DependsOnTask;
```

This returns all tasks where `DependsOnTask` is not null, along with information from that record.

Notes:

- You don't need to use square braces when they are not necessary.  They just clutter up queries.
- Use table aliases and qualify column names, so you know where columns are coming from.
- You need to use an explicit `JOIN` for references back to the same table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a hierarchical structure and task could have a parent and that parent is a child to another task, yo can use recursive CTE to find all hierarchy of determined task.

Let me show an example.

You got structure like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
(1,'Title1','Do some stuff 1', 0, NULL),
(2,'Title2','Do some stuff 2', 0, NULL),
(3,'Title3','Do some stuff 3', 1, 1),
(4,'Title4','Do some stuff 4', 1, 1),
(5,'Title5','Do some stuff 5', 0, 2),
(6,'Title6','Do some stuff 6', 1, 2),
(7,'Title7','Do some stuff 7', 0, 4),
(8,'Title8','Do some stuff 8', 0, NULL)
) as t([id],[title],[description],[complete],[DependsOnTask])
```

So task 1 has 2 child tasks - 3 and 4. The 4th task got 1 child - 7. You want to get all child tasks of task with `id = 1`:

```
DECLARE @taskid int = 1

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [id]
          ,[title]
          ,[description]
          ,[complete]
          ,[DependsOnTask]
    FROM [ToDoItems] 
    WHERE [id] = @taskid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.*
    FROM [ToDoItems] t
    INNER JOIN cte c
        ON c.id = t.DependsOnTask
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
```

Output:

```
id  title   description         complete    DependsOnTask
1   Title1  Do some stuff 1     0           NULL
3   Title3  Do some stuff 3     1           1
4   Title4  Do some stuff 4     1           1
7   Title7  Do some stuff 7     0           4
```

So if you change last select to:

```
SELECT  @taskid as main,
        id,
        DependsOnTask
FROM cte
```

You will get:

```
main    id  DependsOnTask
1       1   NULL
1       3   1
1       4   1
1       7   4
```

So you get all child tasks of `Task1`.

If you change CTE like this:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT [id]
          ,[title]
          ,[description]
          ,[complete]
          ,[DependsOnTask]
          ,[id] as Parent
    FROM [ToDoItems] 
    WHERE [DependsOnTask] IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT  t.*,
            c.Parent
    FROM [ToDoItems] t
    INNER JOIN cte c
        ON c.id = t.DependsOnTask
)

SELECT  Parent,
        id,
        DependsOnTask
FROM cte
```

You will got all you need: Parent task, Child tasks and what are they dependent on:

```
Parent  id  DependsOnTask
1       1   NULL
2       2   NULL
8       8   NULL
2       5   2
2       6   2
1       3   1
1       4   1
1       7   4
```